# Is it possible to use curl after mpdf-> output?

Tags: php, curl, mpdf

**Here is my code**

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$fname = date('Y-m-d-h-s') . "-" . $randomnumber . ".pdf";
$mpdf->Output(__DIR__ . "/../../backend/web/uploads/" . $fname);

$filePath = __DIR__ . "/../../backend/web/uploads/" . $fname;
$filePath = curl_file_create($filePath);
$fileOB = file_get_contents($filePath);
$data = array(
    'token' => $phone,
    'id' => $staff_id,
    'file' => $filePath,
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text/xml'));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

But I can't get response. So,  Is it possible to use curl after `mdpf->output()`?

Update: My php version is less than 5.5

Comment: I'm sorry. This is my first time working with curl and mpdf. That's what I thought. Y-m-d-H-i, I can make it different. @mickmackusa

Comment: My bad. My php version is less than 5.5. So, curl_file_create could not be used. Thank you for your answer. @mickmackusa

Comment: Is this correct? The answer is written below. Thank you @mickmackusa

Comment: I found a duplicate, so I gotta do some housekeeping.

Answer (score 0):

My current php version doesn't have `curl_file_create()`, so I wrote a conditional to use an alternative technique in its absense.

```
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { // php 5.5+
    $filePath = curl_file_create($filePath);
} else {
    $filePath = '@' . realpath($filePath);
}
```

The code is now working correctly.